# How to throw std::invalid_argument error?

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch, inputstream, user-input

I have an overloaded operator in my `Fraction` class in C++ which is designed to take input from standard input in the form of an integer over an integer i.e. `1/2` or `32/4` and initialize a `Fraction` object based off of those values. It works, but I'm having trouble catching errors.

```
// gets input from standard input in the form of (hopefully) int/int
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inputStream, Fraction& frac)
{
    int inputNumerator, inputDenominator;
    char slash;

    if ((std::cin >> inputNumerator >> slash >> inputDenominator) && slash == '/')
    {
        if (inputDenominator == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Denominator must not be 0." << std::endl;
            throw std::invalid_argument("Denominator must not be 0.");
        }
        frac.numerator = inputNumerator;
        frac.denominator = inputDenominator;

        frac.reduce();
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid syntax.");
    }



    return inputStream;
}
```

I invoke the method like this:

```
 Fraction frac(1, 2);


while (true)
{
    try {
        std::cout << "Enter a fraction in the form int/int: ";
        std::cin >> frac;
        std::cout << frac;
    } catch (std::invalid_argument iaex) {
        std::cout << "Caught an error!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But whenever an error is thrown, (I'll enter something like `garbage`) this causes the loop to go on forever without asking for input. What is the reason for this?

Comment: A little comment besides on your code: if you write an input `operator<<`, you should use the srteam passed to it rather than falling back to `std::cin`. Then this can work as expected: `ifstream if(somefile.txt); if >> frac;`

Comment: You also might want to catch exceptions by reference, not by value.

Comment: Adding to what @BitTickler said, the rule-of-thumb for this is: "Throw by **value**, catch by **reference**"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you don't tell us what input you give to your program, I can only guess:

You type something that cin can't parse as the sequence `inputNumerator >> slash >> inputDenominator`, so it goes into a fail state or bad state. The exception gets thrown in the else branch of your function (you can and should test that by printing the exception's message in your main function's catch block).

Your loop in main goes on, but `cin` is left in the bad state, so every following input fails again and the same exception is thrown again and again. To prevent that you should clear the state of cin during the error handling. In addition, if there are bad characters in the input stream that can't be parsed, they have to be thrown out, or `ignore`d:

```
if ((std::cin >> inputNumerator >> slash >> inputDenominator) && slash == '/')
{
  /* ... */
}
else
{
    std::cin.clear(); // reset the fail flags
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //ignore the bad input until line end
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid syntax.");
}
```

Comment: I edited my question a little bit. I can enter any sort of bad input and this will happen. For example `garbage` as input or `steveaoki`. Anyway, I tried this and it didn't work. I am thinking it might have something to do with the fact that I have an inputstream in the function.

Comment: @doctordoder I edited the answer, I missed the `ignore` of the bad input first.

Comment: I actually just found a thread that has the same answer and it worked for me, so yes I can confirm this. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea why it would all fail if I entered just 0?

Comment: @doctordoder it would fail to read the slash and the denominator you explicitly want. Making those optional requires a bit more work.